# confusion with 'this' keyword when using call() within the constructor

Tags: javascript

I have learned the `call()`will bind the `this` keyword with the target object, but i am confused about how can i used the `call()` elegantly within the constructor:

sample code as:

```js
 function Test(x,y){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.calc = (term)=>{
  console.log(term  + (this.x + this.y));
 }
 this.result = () =>{
  let resultA = {
   x:this.x * 20,
   y:this.y * 20
  }

  this.calc.call(resultA,'the result is ');
 }
    }

    var mytest = new Test(20,20);
    
    mytest.result(); //return 'the result is 40' but was expected to be 800
```

the `this.calc()`method was meant to be calling multiple times with different objects declared within the `this.result()` but it is not working as expected, so my questions are:

1. When calling `this.calc.call(resultA);` the `this.x` and `this.y` value is not binding with `resultA.x` and `resultA.y`, i am wondering why is that?
2. Is there any elegant way of using the `call()` or `apply()`method within the constructor?

Comment: expected to be 80?not 800?

Comment: I've addressed #1 in my answer.  Re: #2, what is your actual purpose in using `.call` like this?

Comment: hey @Alnitak thanks for your response, and i was intended to using .call r for drawing circles with different coordinates and colors within an object using canvas API, above code was just demonstrating my queries, thanks for you answer it helps !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using an arrow function, within which `this` is *lexically* bound to the version that's in the enclosing scope, instead of being dynamically assigned via the first parameter to `.call`.

```
this.calc = (term) => {
    // `this` here will *always* be the original constructed object
    console.log(term  + (this.x + this.y));
}
```

To get the behaviour you want you'd have to define `calc` as a "normal" function instead.

Comment: Great answer ! I have a question though which is , why arrow function should behave differently. They are merely a shorter syntax for regular function,aren't they ? Or is there any special reason for introducing arrow function? I don't get the idea.

Comment: @AL-zami they are *not* merely a shorter syntax.  They intentionally have different binding rules for `this`, too.  Sometimes that's a very useful advantage (because it avoids calls to `.bind`).  Sometimes, as in this case, it makes things work in "unexpected" ways.

Comment: then what are the benefits of that ? I see people all around using arrow function only for a substitute of regular functions. What are the special use cases for arrows ?

Comment: @AL-zami e.g. `this.result = array.map(x => x * this.scale)`, where `this.scale` is a property of an object and this code exists inside a method.   The arrow function allows `this.scale` to reference the current object without having to explicitly pass the context.   This isn't perhaps the best example since `Array#map` does support passing the context as the third parameter, though!

Comment: OP here called the calc function from inside of result function. Will 'this' will be bound to originally constructed object even if it's called from outside.

Comment: @AL-zami yes, because `resultA` is derived from `this.x` and `this.y` but since `this.resultA` is an arrow function those two references to `this` will *always* be to the outer `this` from the `Test` constructor's scope.